# zsh: Ubuntu like prompt for helping installing software

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

I run xubuntu and am switching from bash to zsh as the default shell. It works great - only thing I miss from the bash days is this: when I execute a command which isn't installed, bash would tell me the apt-get command line for installing it. Is it possible to achieve this with zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be already answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34978/configuring-to-detect-if-a-command-does-not-exist-suggest-installation).

The response is issued by the `command-not-found` package, which you obviously already have, since `bash` is responding as you wish. It is simply a matter of configuring `zsh` to use it.

After trying the solution in Ubuntu I found that the file mentioned in `/etc` doesn't exist, but it is simply a matter of adding this line to `.zshrc`:

```
command_not_found_handler() {/usr/lib/command-not-found "$1"}
```

If you want to suppress `zsh`'s own `command not found` message, you can add `return 0` to the handler, **BUT** this will not show an error in `$?` afterwards.

There is more information on how `bash` interfaces to the package [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67466/how-to-implement-package-install-suggestion-on-debian).

Note that the `bash` handler is called `command_not_found_handle()`, whereas in `zsh` it's `command_not_found_handler()`.